# Error when going from dataframe to excel file in Julia

Tags: excel, dataframe, julia, xlsx

I am trying to export a dataframe to xlsx

```
df |> XLSX.writexlsx("df.xlsx")
```

and am getting this error:

```
ERROR: Unsupported datatype String31 for writing data to Excel file. Supported data types are Union{Missing, Bool, Float64, Int64, Dates.Date, Dates.DateTime, Dates.Time, String} or XLSX.CellValue.
```

I cannot find anyting about `String31` utilizing Google. Is there a "transform" that I need to perform on the df beforehand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that currently this is a limitation of XSLX.jl. I have opened [an issue](https://github.com/felipenoris/XLSX.jl/issues/201) proposing to fix it.

I assume your `df` is not huge, in which case the following solution should work for you:

```
to_string(x::AbstractString) = String(x)
to_string(x::Any) = x
XLSX.writetable("df.xlsx", to_string.(df))
```

Comment: Getting this error: `ERROR: MethodError: no method matching writexlsx(::String)`

Comment: I thought this part of your question was working. I have checked the documentation of XLSX.jl and it recommends using `XLSX.writetable`. I have updated the answer.

Comment: I forgot about `XLSX.writetable()`. I found that earlier working on something also.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you're reading the data in from a CSV file? CSV.jl uses fixed-length strings from the InlineStrings.jl package when it reads from a file, which can be much better for managing memory allocation, and hence for performance. For eg.:

```
julia> df = CSV.read(IOBuffer("S, I, F
                   hello Julian world, 2, 3.14"), DataFrame)
1×3 DataFrame
 Row │ S                    I      F      
     │ String31            Int64  Float64 
─────┼────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ hello Julian world      2     3.14
```

Here, the `S` column was assigned a `String31` type since that's the smallest type from `InlineStrings` that can hold our string.

However, it looks like XLSX.jl doesn't know how to handle `InlineString` types, unfortunately.

You can [specify when reading the file](https://csv.juliadata.org/stable/reading.html#stringtype) that you want all strings to be read as just `String` type and not the fixed-length `InlineString` variety.

```
julia> df = CSV.read(IOBuffer("S, I, F
                   hello Julian world, 2, 3.14"), DataFrame, stringtype = String)
1×3 DataFrame
 Row │ S                    I      F      
     │ String              Int64  Float64 
─────┼────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ hello Julian world      2     3.14
```

Or, you can transform the column just before writing to the file.

```
julia> transform!(df, :S => ByRow(String) => :S)
1×3 DataFrame
 Row │ S                    I      F      
     │ String              Int64  Float64 
─────┼────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ hello Julian world      2     3.14
```

If you have multiple `InlineString` type columns and don't want to specify them individually, you can also do:

```
julia> to_string(c::AbstractVector) = c;

julia> to_string(c::AbstractVector{T}) where T <: AbstractString = String.(c);

julia> mapcols!(to_string, df)
1×3 DataFrame
 Row │ S                    I      F      
     │ String              Int64  Float64 
─────┼────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ hello Julian world      2     3.14
```

*(Edited to use multiple dispatch here (based on Bogumil Kaminsky's answer) rather than typecheck in the function.)*

Comment: The difference is that my solution is slower, but more robust. What Sundar R proposes will be better most of the time. However, in rare cases if your columns have heterogeneous elements, and e.g. have `Any` or `Union{Missing, AbstractString}` eltype it will not work.

Comment: True. It seemed like an `InlineString` type being part of a heterogenous column would be unlikely, but the `Union{Missing, ...}` is definitely an important possibility that I didn't consider.